# How can we check NSURL variable is nil or not before using it?

Tags: swift2, nsurl

We defined a NSURL variable as

```
var audioURL_iPOD: NSURL?
```

In one part of the code we used to get a song url using

```
    let audioItem    = selectedAudio.objectAtIndex(0)
     audioURL_iPOD   = audioItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL
```

In an other place in our code we had to check  if audioURL_iPOD was nil or not. But

```
       if audioURL_iPOD?.absoluteString == nil {  do something    }
```

did not work as usual and returned

```
      fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

So we have to do something more complicated unless we are able to find a way checking audioURL_iPOD was nil or not.

Comment: What do you mean "did not work"? Did the block run even when the URL was `nil`?

Comment: sometimes is a man just too tired ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check for `nil` using optional binding:

```
if let absStr = audioURL_iPOD?.absoluteString {  
 // do something with absStr being NOT nil
} else {
 // do something with absStr being nil
}
```

Comment: _if let something = etc {   }_ is kind of unusual but whatever works fine with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

```
guard let safeAudioURLiPod = audioItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL else { 
    /* exit scope by returning or throwing */ 
}
```

and then proceed to use the safeAudioURLiPod as if it wasn't an optional

example: `safeAudioURLiPod.absoluteString` without the optional chain